# remote FileChooser using OtrosVFSBrowser

Tags: java, jfilechooser, jsch, otroslogviewer

I'm trying to do a remote filechooser. I read a lot of information but I don't get it.
The best site I've seen is (https://code.google.com/p/otrosvfsbrowser/) because is exactly what I want but I don't fine more information. Are Someone of you using this tool? where are any example code?
I already use JSCH library to transfer via SFTP, but I want a tool to choose the remote path.
I'm starting in Java. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3):

You can check example code on [Usage page](https://code.google.com/p/otrosvfsbrowser/wiki/Usage)
You can just create dialog and register action on approve:

```
JOtrosVfsBrowserDialog jOtrosVfsBrowserDialog = new JOtrosVfsBrowserDialog();
Action a = new AbstractAction("Select file") {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (JOtrosVfsBrowserDialog.ReturnValue.Approve.equals(jOtrosVfsBrowserDialog.showOpenDialog(TestDialog.this,"title"))){
        String friendlyUrl = jOtrosVfsBrowserDialog.getSelectedFile().getName().getFriendlyURI();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks @KrzyH ! I already try this but only allow me to view in my local machine. It doesn't show me the possibility to view the files from the remote places.

Comment: try to open url like sftp://user@host.com:/path/